# Non-USB powered laptop cooling pad?

Tags: laptop, usb, power, cooling-pad

On my laptop (el-cheapo but pretty good) I have all my 3 USB ports occupied by devices in use (external mouse, external keyboard, 3G internet/flash drive/external hard drive/etc).

I want a cooling pad for my hard-worked laptop but all seem to be powered by USB...

This laptop is mainly stationary. Either is available a solution to power the USB-powered cooling pad other than connecting it to the laptop...

... either is there a non-USB powered laptop cooling pad?

Comment: Something to be aware of: "USB-powered" fans are a lie.  They all exceed the USB specification with regard to inrush current, sleep current, negotiation for current.  The ones with pass-through USB port are the worst, because the device actually plugged in *will* negotiate current based on its requirements, and then the fan exceeds the negotiated levels constantly.  As a result, they should never be plugged into a USB host, only a charger with USB-shaped power (and no data connection) like Leftium mentioned.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are two types of USB peripherals that may help you out:

- A [USB hub](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/USB_hub) will allow you to increase the number of USB ports on your laptop.
- A [USB to AC adapter](http://www.thinkgeek.com/gadgets/travelpower/9124/) will allow you to plug the cooling pad directly into a wall socket.

A USB to AC adapter looks like this:

[image]

Comment: I've tried an USB hub and my USB mouse was so slow and hic-upped that it coulnd't be used. I guess the USB/AC adapter seems better :)

Comment: @Andrei: try using the hub only for devices where sensitivity to latency is not a problem: the cooling pad and flash drives.

Answer (score 2):

A small mains powered fan pointing to the underside of the laptop.

Artificial feet to raise the laptop a few centimetres and allow more air to circulate.

Answer (score 1):

There are three options:

There is a company making a mat containing some sort of ?salt? crystals that are hard and crunchy under normal temperatures, but become fluid under heat.  This result in the mat adsorbing the heat and dissipating it throughout itself.  Best Buy sells them.

Second option is that you can simply buy a 5 volt adapter from someplace like RadioShack (yeah, I know, but the new name's STUPID) - just bring down the original cable to match the plug.  Then you plug it into AC power.

Third option is to simply raise the back of the laptop on some sort of mesh wedge so airflow is increased.

BTW, Targus used to make 5 volt AC adapters for their USB powered fan coolers.  You can see if you can order from them for whatever current versions they have.

Answer (score 0):

There are various ones like this on Ebay:

Targus AWE12USX Laptop Cooling Pad Dual Fan USB 2.0 Ports Power Adapter Notebook

Hope that helps.

Comment: Read over ["Why do I need 50 reputation to comment"](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead) to ensure you understand how you can start commenting.

Answer (score -2):

Cooling master notepal comes with a power adapter. Hope that helps.